# Marking outliers in time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a df of thousands of entries of particular lab value for patients with each row representing one instance they had the lab taken. I am interested in looking at the change in this value over time after a surgery. If the value rises and falls back to baseline within an acute time period I need to exclude the rise, however if it rises and stays above baseline I need to keep these values. I am able to mark if the value rises past a certain threshold within a time period, but I'm unsure how to code if it returns to baseline within a particular range of time. My ultimate goal is to use a geom_smooth to trend the value over time based on a particular procedure type, but need to exclude these outliers for my graphs to be correct. Any help would be very appreciated!

My data is organized like this:

| lab Date | Lab value | study ID | Acutely Past threshold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 2 | 1 | NA |
| 4/1/2001 | 2.3 | 1 | N |
| 5/2/2002 | 2.3 | 1 | N |
| 4/8/2018 | 1 | 2 | NA |
| 4/9/2018 | 3.8 | 2 | Y |
| 4/15/2018 | 1 | 2 | N |
| 5/1/2016 | 1.0 | 3 | NA |
| 5/2/2016 | 1.2 | 3 | N |
| 4/1/1997 | 1.0 | 4 | NA |
| 4/4/1997 | 2.5 | 4 | Y |
| 5/5/1997 | 2.5 | 4 | N |

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, when posting data it is better to use dput in order to provide a reproducible example.
I thinking something like this might work. You would need to identify the "episodes" in which the value went over the threshold.
In this code, the output I think you're looking for is "episode"

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    potential_episode_grp = (lab_value > normal_level) * data.table::rleid(lab_value > normal_level)
  ) %>%
  group_by(id, potential_episode_grp) %>%
  mutate(episode = as.integer(potential_episode_grp > 0 & any(lab_value > threshold_you_want)))
```